# Plot multiple columns using pandas and plotly timeline

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, timeline, gantt-chart

There are multiple questions on plotting multiple graphs but not specifically for pandas and timelines.

I have a dataframe like the below:

| Name | day_1_start | day_1_end | day_2_start | day_2_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1:00pm | 3:00pm | 3:30pm | 5:30pm |
| B | 11:00am | 1:00pm | 3:45pm | 4:30pm |
| C | 10:00am | 11:00am | 11:30am | 4:30pm |

I am trying to plot this into a gantt chart/timeline. Using `plotly.express.timeline`, is it possible to have multiple `x_start` and `x_end`? Namely, can I have `day_1_start` and `day_2_start` both be used as `x_start` and `day_1_end` and `day_2_end` used as `x_end`?

I believe I can also solve this by creating a new table (like the below example) but wondering if it's possible without needing to do this transformation as it's expensive.

| Name | start | end | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1:00pm | 3:00pm | 1 |
| A | 3:30pm | 5:30pm | 2 |
| B | 11:00am | 1:00pm | 1 |
| B | 3:45pm | 4:30pm | 2 |

This is roughly what I'd like to end up with with day 1 and day 2 shown as different colors - from [https://plotly.com/python/gantt/]](https://plotly.com/python/gantt/%5D)
[image: This is roughly what I'd like to end up with - from https://plotly.com/python/gantt/]

Comment: What is the expectation for day1 and day2 in terms of X-axis? Will they need to be 24 hrs apart or is only the time that matters? Colors for the bar are based on jobs (A,B,C,) right?

Comment: Why is the transformation expensive, i.e. time consuming? For typical amounts of data to  show in a plot, this should take no time, and, imho, it's the cleanest option to achieve your goal.

Comment: day1 vs day2 - only the time matters. It is a date/time in UTC. Colors of the bar are based on what day, not jobs

Comment: I could be naive, but I assume a transformation is expensive when I'm looking to re-render this dashboard with different filters quickly. I have hundreds of jobs/people. I'm open to transforming the data if theres a quick or easy way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Since the combination of two time series cannot be treated as a single time series, the wide format needs to be converted to long format. `wide_to_long()` could not be used to keep multiple columns, so I created a data frame for each target unit, though poorly, and joined them vertically. There may be other, more elegant ways to do this. If I can do it in vertical format, I can draw a timeline with `px.timeline()` or `ff.create_gantt()`. `ff.create_gannt()` has a column name specified, so I changed it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
Name day_1_start day_1_end day_2_start day_2_end
A 1:00pm 3:00pm 3:30pm 5:30pm
B 11:00am 1:00pm 3:45pm 4:30pm
C 10:00am 11:00am 11:30am 4:30pm
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

df_d1 = df[['Name','day_1_start','day_1_end']]
df_d1 = df_d1.assign(day=['day_1']*len(df_d1)).rename(columns={'day_1_start':'start','day_1_end':'end'})

df_d2 = df[['Name','day_2_start','day_2_end']]
df_d2 = df_d2.assign(day=['day_2']*len(df_d2)).rename(columns={'day_2_start':'start','day_2_end':'end'})
df_long = pd.concat([df_d1,df_d2],axis=0, ignore_index=True)

df_long['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df_long['start'])
df_long['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df_long['end'])
```

**px.line**

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

fig = px.timeline(df_long, x_start="start", x_end="end", y="Name", color="day")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.show()
```

[image]

**ff.create_gannt**

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

colors = {'day_1': 'rgb(220, 0, 0)', 'day_2': 'rgb(0, 255, 100)'}
df_long_ff = df_long.copy()
df_long_ff.columns = ['Task', 'Start', 'Finish', 'Resource']
fig = ff.create_gantt(df_long_ff, colors=colors, index_col='Resource', show_colorbar=True, group_tasks=True)
fig.show()
```

[image]